# Does this equation hold? $ P(A \cap B \cap C | D \cap E) = P(A \cap B \cap (C | D \cap E)) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Does this equation hold? Can we treat conditioning and intersection operation associative?

Comment: Your statement doesn't have sence. What do you mean by value like this: $Pr(A  \cap (B | C))$?

Comment: @BotnakovN. is right, at first glance $A|B$ does not have sense, only $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$.

Comment: Think about it as an event. Event of "C happening given event D and E happened".
On the other hand the other one is the event of "A, B and C happening together given that events D and E happened".

Comment: @I don't know how you could define $C| (D \cap E)$ as an event.

Comment: @EmreKara, it still doesn't have sence. You said: *Event of "C happening given event D and E happened"*. And what about $A$? It looks like l.h.s. and r.h.s. are the same. Give an example of situation in which l.h.s. and r.h.s. differs.

Comment: Let us assume we know that $Pr( C | D \cap E) = Pr(C | D )$. Can we say that $Pr(A \cap B \cap C | D \cap E) = Pr(A \cap B \cap C | D) $

Comment: @EmreKara, if it's your question, so it's better to make an edit.

Comment: @BotnakovN. Can we say that both definitions definitely refer to the same set of events? $( (A\cap B\cap C) | (D\cap E) ) $ and $( (A\cap B) \cap (C| (D\cap E) ) $ both refer to the sets of events. The question is "do they refer to the same set of events?". It is a question about parenthesis at some point. I have no idea how can I make this question more clear to the community.

Comment: @EmreKara, notice that now you got rid of probabilities. So the question from your last comment differs from the question from the question, from the your comment before it.

Comment: @BotnakovN. I did it to make it clearer. Probability is about sets of events. I kindly request that please provide an answer to the question if you know, otherwise I am not looking for advises but thanks for your intention.

Comment: @EmreKara, there are two questions: about Pr(A∩B∩C|D∩E)=Pr(A∩B∩C|D) and about  ((A∩B∩C)|(D∩E))  and ((A∩B)∩(C|(D∩E)). The first one have sense, the second one doesn't have sence.

Comment: @EmreKara On an ordinary day, take: A="My souffle would rise", B="I will be happy", C="I can make the souffle mix", D="I happen to have all the ingredients" and E="My oven is broken". $Pr(C\mid D\cap E)=Pr(C\mid D)\approx 100\%$ as E doesn't matter for making the dough, but $0=Pr(A\cap B\cap C\mid D\cap E)\ne Pr(A\cap B\cap C\mid D)$ because some days my souffles are fine and I am happy, but obviously it never comes particularly nicely from a cold oven.

Comment: @EmreKara, if you are not looking for advises about your problem then it's better to delete this question and not to waste time of people, who try to help. If you are looking for advises about your problem then you have to write it in a proper way.

Answer (score 2):

Conditioning is not an operation on events. Let $\Omega$ denote the sample space and $\mathcal F\subseteq\mathcal P(\Omega)$ denote the set of events (a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$). While intersection takes two events $A,B\in\mathcal F$ to a new event $A\cap B\in\mathcal F$, conditioning is an operation on probability measures:

Given any event $B\in\mathcal F$ with $P(B)\neq 0$, it takes the probability measure $P\colon \mathcal F\to[0,1]$ to a new probability measure $P({-}\mid B)\colon \mathcal F\to [0,1]$ given by
$$
P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}.
$$

Here "$A\mid B$" is not an event or anything considered on its own. The notation $P(A\mid B)$ should be read as the probability of $A$ under the conditioned measure $P({-}\mid B)$.

Hence, an expression of the kind $P(X\cap(Y\mid Z))$ is meaningless, since it is not of the kind $P(\ldots\mid B)$ and the notation "$Y\mid Z$" on its own has no meaning.

Comment: $P(X\cap (Y|Z))$, the probability of $X$ and $Y$ divides $Z$?